# Javascript - Append select lists from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i auto generate multiple select lists from a select list like this example :

[image]

My code :

**HTML**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="multiple.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="selected_form_code">
        <select id="select_btn">
                <option value="0">--How many rooms ?--</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="form_submit">
        <!-- Dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#select_btn').change(
        function() {
            var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
            $("#form_submit").empty(); //Resetting Form
            // Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically
            create(sel_value);
            // Appending Submit Button To Form
        }
    );
    function create(sel_value) {     
        for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++) {
            $("div#form1").append($("#form_submit"
                         ).append($("<div/>", {id: 'head' }
                         ).append($("<b>").text("Chambre " + i)), 
                            $("<input/>", 
                                { type: 'text', placeholder: 'Chambre ' + i, name: 'Chambre-' + i } ) ))
        }
    }
});
```

This code only create text inputs. But, i need to display multiple rooms (chambre) by selecting the number from select option. After that, if il select N kids (enfants), N select should appears to choose their ages.

I hope it's clear :)

Comment: Any help please ?  :'(

Comment: your JS code is quite messy. however, what's the result of it?

Comment: That's it https://jsfiddle.net/v1okgzw0/1/

Comment: seems you on the right way... what is unclear for you? you now need to create same code for adults and infants and a function like subcreate(chambre_id, adults_value, infants_value)

Comment: Yes, but i can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, i'm not a big jquery fan, but as nobody answers, i try.

so fist, i would made some function get_chambre_html(cn) that will generate some Chambre html block, to append it in 'for' loop in your create().

then, next line after append() in create() function we may add change() event listeners for each new block, like you do it for chambres.

to add additional fields for each child we will append them to `$('#ages'+chambre_index)[0]`

```
<html><body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="selected_form_code">
            <select id="select_btn">
                    <option value="0">--How many rooms ?--</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div id="form_submit">
    <!-- Dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates Here -->
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function get_chambre_html(cn)
{
  return "<div>"
      + "<b>Chambre " + cn + ":</b> "
      + "Adultes: <select id='adultes" + cn + "'>"
      + "<option value='0'>--How many adults ?--</option>"
      + "<option value='1'>1</option>"
      + "<option value='2'>2</option></select>"
      + "<br/>Enfants: <select id='enfants" + cn + "'>"
      + "<option value='0'>--How many enfants ?--</option>"
      + "<option value='1'>1</option>"
      + "<option value='2'>2</option></select>"
      + "<div id='ages" + cn + "'></div>" // empty block for further usage
    +"</div>";
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('select#select_btn').change(function()
  {
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
    $("#form_submit").empty(); //Resetting Form
    // Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically
    create(sel_value);
    // Appending Submit Button To Form
  });


  function create(sel_value)
  {
    for (var i = 1; i <= sel_value; i++)
    {
      $("div#form1").append($("#form_submit").append(get_chambre_html(i)));
      $("div#form1").append($("#form_submit").append("<div id='ages"+i+"'/>"));
      $('select#enfants'+i).change(function(){
        var infants = this.value;
        var i=this.id.substr(7); // 7 = strlen of 'enfants'
        for(var j=0; j<infants; j++)
          $('#ages'+i).append(':[input age block '+i+']: ');
      });
    }
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Almost perfect ! I changed the enfants part, just two litte fixes. The switch of number of enfants and "Age enfant" should strat with 1 not 0. https://jsfiddle.net/v1okgzw0/2/

Comment: Any help please ? :(

Comment: What help do you need now?

Comment: Two small issues with the Enfants select menu. The number start with 0 not 1. And the change of the Enfants number doesn't look correct

Comment: PERFECT ! Thank you !

Comment: Update: How can i add a another select menu (Seniors) like "Enfants" ? i can't do it ...

Comment: Can you help me please @kay27 ?

Comment: I'd recommend you to read http://www.w3schools.com/ occasionally, it is enthralling and helpful. I don't think it is right to do your work for you... Though I love to help